# Getting "wrong number of arguments" error on finder method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, arguments, finder

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 (and using MySQL 5.5.37).  I’m having difficulty writing a finder method for one of my models.  I have columns “user,” “object,” and “day”, but the following

```
  def find_by_user_object_and_day
    respond_to do |format|
      @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
      format.js {
        render :text => Userobject.find_by_user_and_object_and_day(:user => @current_user, :object => params[:object], :day => params[:day]) 
      }
    end
  end
```

produces the error

```
F, [2016-02-05T16:49:42.934112 #12058] FATAL -- : 
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)):
  app/controllers/user_objects_controller.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in find_by_user_object_and_day'
  app/controllers/user_objects_controller.rb:74:in `find_by_user_object_and_day'
```

How do I properly specify the arguments to the finder method?  I haven’t explicitly defined that finder method because I thought the “and” syntax would work.

Comment: can you post the `find_by_user_and_object_and_day` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3))
```

This means you're supposed to pass in 3 distinct arguments, but you passed in 1. It looks like you passed in a hash of values instead of standalone values.

Replace:

```
 Userobject.find_by_user_and_object_and_day(:user => @current_user, :object => params[:object], :day => params[:day])
```

With this:

```
Userobject.find_by_user_and_object_and_day(@current_user, params[:object], params[:day])
```

Comment: Still looks like 3 args to me?... although you are right with their declarations

Comment: It's supposed to be 3 args: `(wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3))`. He was submitting only 1 argument (the hash)

Answer (score 0):

`find_by_some_column_and_another` ([dynamic finders](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013)) have been deprecated in favour of [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) in Rails 4+:

```
@user = UserObject.find_by user: @current_user, object: params[:object], day: params[:day]
```

---

Using the above code structure *should* solve your issue (`find_by` takes a hash and *requires* only `1` argument).

If you still want to use your dynamic find method, you need to ensure you have both the `params[:object]` and `params[:day]` values populated, as well as dropping the `user:`/`object:`/`day:` declarations (as mentioned by `@miler350`)

---

Secondarily, you also need to make sure that you're constructing your actions properly:

```
def find_by_user_object_and_day
    @current_user = User.find session["user_id"]
    @user_object  = UserObject.find_by user: @current_user, object: params[:object], day: params[:day] 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render text: @user_object }
    end
end
```